# How to get the xml attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

I have an aggregation which produce output like this but I need to get the name from the key using xpath, I'm new to this xml, please advise.

```
<Aggregation name="area">
      <Set key="name">
        <Entry key="docCount">20</Entry>
      </Set>
      <Set key="name1">
        <Entry key="docCount">16</Entry>
      </Set>
      <Set key="name2">
        <Entry key="docCount">12</Entry>
      </Set>
      </Aggregation>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you clearly state the exact result you seek to select from your example, we can easily help you write an XPath for it.  As your question stands, it's unclear what you you're trying to do.

Comment: @kjhughes I have queried the data from data and its generating the report in xml as mentioned above and I want to retrieve the key attribute of each set. finally I did it. let me know if you know any good site to refer xpath and  xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally, I have retrieved the value

```
 <Report>
             <for-each select="$docSets" in="docSet">   
                <Key>{$docSet/@key}</Key>
                <Value>{$docSet//Entry/text()}</Value>
            </for-each>
   </Report>
```